# Getter for large member variables w/o copying

Tags: c++, oop

I have a class containing large member variables. In my case, the large member variable is a container of many objects and it must be private as I don't want to allow a user to modify it directly

```
class Example {
 public:
  std::vector<BigObject> get_very_big_object() const { return very_big_object; }
 private:
  std::vector<BigObject> very_big_object;
}
```

I want a user to be able to view the object without making a copy:

```
Example e();
auto very_big_object = e.get_very_big_object();  // Uh oh, made a copy
cout << very_big_object[11];  // Look at any element in the vector etc
```

I'm a bit confused about the best way to do it. I thought about returning a constant reference, i.e., make my getter:

```
const std::vector<BigObject>& get_very_big_object() const { return very_big_object; }
```

I read [this article](https://thesyntacticsugar.blogspot.com/2011/09/evil-side-of-returning-member-as-const.html) that suggests it could be risky and that that a smart pointer `std::unique_ptr` could be better, but that this problem can be best solved using modern C++11 move semantics. But I found that a bit cryptic.

What's the modern best practice for doing this?

Comment: I can't seem to access the article, and I'd like to read it since I disagree with the statement that a constant reference is risky. For your use case, it seems to be the best and most straight forward solution. This is not a good use case for move semantics or std::unique_ptrs.

Comment: @azam Sorry, I have no idea what happened with the link, now fixed

Comment: Agreed with Azam. We don't make variables `const` for security. We do it to inform the user about our intended use of the library. Anyone with access to your library has access to any variable they want. If someone goes through the trouble to turn your `const &` into a non-`const &`, then they deserve the problems they get.

Comment: The problem here is that if you ask ten C++ developers "what's the modern best practice for doing <X>" you will always get at least eleven different answers.

Comment: The other example of trying to access a variable after the owning object goes out of scope is a problem if you're in the habit of accessing references and pointers after the original object goes out of scope. I agree this can be a problem for a beginner or even some intermediate C++ programmers. And there's a non-zero number of lines of production code written by such people so it is a valid problem, but it's on the same level as any other misuse of the language. In C++ you're allowed to shoot yourself in the foot. That's one of its characteristics.

Comment: If you're afraid of your users getting a reference, destroying the object, and then dereferencing the reference, there are other languages that handle this  automatically like Python and (I think) Java where everything has a reference counter and is a shared pointer essentially.

Comment: @Sam haha, but in this case, it seems like there might be some agreement here that const refs are the best solution...

Comment: Returning a `const` reference avoids copying. That is risky if the caller takes specific steps (e.g. uses a typecast to discard the `const`, and then changes the private data). Most such actions by the caller involve undefined behaviour - due to the nature of undefined behaviour, that can't be prevented in C++. If the caller introduces undefined behaviour - deliberately or accidentally - then the caller must deal with that. If you want to protect your class data from deliberate actions by the calling code, then you need to use a language other than C++.

Comment: @JohnFilleau C++ has `std::shared_ptr` for that same thing.

Comment: @Remy yeah but you have to put in effort to use that. Python does it magically. My bad. Wasn't saying you can't do it in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I read [this article](https://thesyntacticsugar.blogspot.com/2011/09/evil-side-of-returning-member-as-const.html) that suggests it could be risky and that that a smart pointer `std::unique_ptr` could be better, but that this problem can be best solved using modern C++11 move semantics.

On this point, the article is flat-out wrong. A smart pointer does not remove the "risk".

**Quick summary of relevant parts of the article**

- If a class returns a `const` reference to a data member, client code may introduce a `const_cast` and thereby change the data member without going through the class' API.
- The article proposes *(incorrectly)* that the above can be avoided by using a smart pointer. The setup is for the class to maintain a shared pointer to the data, and have the getter return that pointer cast to a shared pointer to `const` data.

**Critique of the points**

First of all, this does not work. All one has to do is de-reference the smart pointer to get a `const` reference to the data, which can then be `const_cast` as before. Using the author's own example, instead of

```
std::string &evil = const_cast<std::string&>(obj.someStr());
```

use

```
std::string &evil = const_cast<std::string&>(*obj.str_ptr());
```

to get the same data-changing results when returning a smart pointer. The entire article is not wrong, but it does get several points wrong. This is one of them.

Second of all, this is not your concern. When you return a `const` reference, you are telling client code that this value is not to be changed. If the client code does so anyway, it's the client code that broke the agreement. Essentially, the client code invoked undefined behavior, so your class is free to do anything, even crash the program.

> What's the modern best practice for doing this?

Simply return a `const` reference. (Most rules have exceptions, but in my experience, this one seems to be on target 95-99.9% of the time.)

Comment: In other words: don't believe everything you read on the Internet. And you know you can take this advice because you read it on the Internet. :)

Comment: You were way more fair to that party than I would have been.  Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I did when I was working on my BDD-library for school is to create a wrapper class called `VeryBigObject`, which contacts the singleton upon instantiation and hides a reference-counting pointer, from there you can override the `operator->()` method to allow for direct access to the class's methods.

So something like this

```cpp
class VeryBigObject {
private:
  vector<BigObject>* obj;
public:
  VeryBigObject() {
    // find a way to instantiate with a pointer, not by copying
  }
  VeryBigObject(const VeryBigObject& o) {
    // Update reference counts
    obj = o.obj;
  }
  virtual VeryBigObject operator->(const VeryBigObject&); // I don't remember how to do this one, just google it.
  ... // Do other overloads as you see fit to mask working with the pointer directly.
};
```

This allows you to create a small portable class that you don't have to worry about copying, but also has access to the larger object easily. You'll still need to worry about things like caching and such though

Comment: You probably meant `vector<BigObject>* operator->() { return obj; };` and you would need to increment the refcount in the constructor too, and add a destructor to decrement it. And add an assignment operator. And maybe add `operator*` or `operator vector<BigObject>&()`. And maybe store a reference instead of a pointer

Comment: yes, I'm well aware that my code is missing several bits, I assume the reader can understand what I'm intending to get across, regardless, the code is supplementary